# doctrine nested entities cascade persist : how to reuse existing entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

If entity A contains multiple entity B and has cascade:persist, how to reuse existing entities B when persisting ?

B entity has one primary key, an integer, and the id of the A parent. The only data it contains is the primary key.

Example:
A has 2 B entities, identified by their id, 14 and 23.

```
A.Bs = [{id=14, AId=A.id}, {id=23, AId=A.Id}]
```

Now if I modify this managed entity, to add a B entity to A, with id = 56.

```
A.Bs = [{id=14, AId=A.id}, {id=23, AId=A.Id}, {id=56}]
```

---

Relationships

**Entity A**

```
/**
 * @var B[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="A", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
private $Bs;
```

**Entity B**

```
/**
 * @var A
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="Bs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="A_id", referencedColumnName="A_id")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $A;
```

---

If I try to persist I get `Integrity constraint violation`, because Doctrine tries to persist the existing entities, that have id 14 and 23.

I understand this is expected behaviour, but how can I make it persist new entities, and reuse existing ones ?

---

More details:

If I get an existing entity A with `$em->find($id)` and directly use persist and flush, I will get `UniqueConstraintException` because it tries to persist the already persisted B entities.

Example code:

```
/** @var A $existingEntityA */
$existingEntityA = $this->getEntity($id);
$this->serializerFactory->getComplexEntityDeserializer()->deserialize(json_encode($editedEntityADataJson), A::class, 'json', ['object_to_populate' => $existingEntityA]);

$this->entityValidator->validateEntity($existingEntityA);

$this->_em->flush();
```

Example error : Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '777111' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your example properly - you're doing something like this:

```
$b = new B();
$b->setId(56);
$a->getB()->add($b);
```

and you having a row with primary key `56` into database table that is represented by `B`?

If my assumption is correct - it is wrong way to go. Reason is that Doctrine internally stores so called "identity map" that keeps track of all entities that either being fetched from database or persisted by calling `EntityManager::persist()`. Every entity that is scheduled for commit but not available into identity map is considered as "new" and scheduled for insertion. If row with same primary key is already available in database - you're receiving `UniqueConstraintException`.

Doctrine doesn't handle a case "let me look if there is an entity with such primary key in database" by itself because it will hurt performance significantly and is not needed in most cases. Each such test will result into database query, imagine if you will have thousands of such entities. Since Doctrine doesn't know business logic of your application - it will spend even more resources with attempts to guess optimal strategy so this is intentionally left out of scope.

Correct way for you would be to get your entity by itself before adding to collection:

```
$newB = $em->find(B::class, 56);
if ($newB) {
  $a->getB()->add($newB);
}
```

In this case new entity will internally have "managed" status and will be correctly handled by Doctrine at a time of commit.

Comment: I am implementing edit entity A feature, so I get an existing A using entity manager, and edit it. When I get an existing A and try to persist it, it throws this error, even when I don't add a new B.

Comment: I added more details at the bottom of the original post

Comment: This scenario is different from one that is originally explained into your question. Usually it is bad practice to update question in such manner. What is actual exception message that you're getting from Doctrine?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but the OP states it the already existing entities B that cause the issues : error is : Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '777111' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I was mistaken about the error tho, which is Integrity constraint violation and not UniqueConstraintException, my bad

Comment: How do `deserialize()` in your example relates with `$existingEntityA`? Reason for asking is a fact that if you're **deserializing** contents of `B` entities named into your initial example - then you'll face the same issue.

Comment: I deserialize the new entity state into the existing entity using object_to_populate. So you mean I have to add the B with add($newB), as in your answer to avoid that ?

Comment: I mean that if you're deserializing entities - you have to fetch them from Doctrine before filling with data during deserialization process. I'm not sure what serializer library you're using, but you need to check how do it dealing with Doctrine. Most likely source of your issue lies somewhere into this deserialization process - objects themselves may look correct, but entity states are different into Doctrine's identity map and it results into incorrect SQL queries to be generated by Doctrine

Comment: I just made a wrapper arround symfony serializer. What is weird is when I dump the content of A->getBs(), the Bs contain correct data about A, so I would expect doctrine to understand that these Bs belong to A. You must be right, in that the problem must be doctrine not getting that... thanks for your help

Comment: If this information came from external source (I mean `Request` object) that you should better not convert it directly to entities because it can't be considered as "trusted". And yes, main reason is that `$b = new B()` and `$b = $em->find(B::class, $id)` both results into instance of `B`, but they have different status in Doctrine and hence resulted SQL requests will be different. It may not look obvious at a first sight, but it is an important aspect to remember.

Comment: I think I get it... thanks for explaining. It is true it is a security issue, but because it is an internal project, I am not sure that kind of data injection should be considered a problem, I will raise the point in a meeting tho :)